# How do I implement the code for an unsigned 4-bit multiplier

Tags: verilog

I am trying to create a 4-bit multiplier using behavioral Verilog with assignment statements and procedural blocks if possible. The circuit I am trying to replicate is this one :

[image: 4-Bit Multiplier]

So far, I defined the submodule `fouralu_adder` which is a simple unsigned 4-bit adder. Then I wrote the following psuedo-code:

```
module fouralu_multi(
    input [3:0] A_i,//Input signals
    input [3:0] B_i,
    output [7:0] S_o//Output signal 
    );
    wire [4:0] S1,S2;//These were supposed to be the SUM wires coming out of AD1 and AD2
    wire [3:0] AND; 
    fouralu_adder AD1(
    //Port connections here
    );
     
    fouralu_adder AD2(
    //Port connections here
    );
    fouralu_adder AD3(
       //Port connections here
    );
endmodule
```

The initial idea I had was to somehow assign the behavior of the and gates with something like :
`assign AND = A_i&B_i[0];` then repeat for each value of `B_i` but quickly realized it would be quite an inefficient approach. This leads me to ask the question : How do I implement the circuit using behavioral verilog? How am I to connect the input ports to the submodule without using structural verilog, and with as little `wire` variables as possible? Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for loop, google it and you'll learn how to use it.

For example

```
integer idx;

reg [3:0] A_AND_B [0:3];

always @(*)begin
    for( idx=0; idx<4; idx=idx+1) A_AND_B[idx] = {4{B[idx]}} & A;
end
```

this code equals to

```
reg [3:0] A_AND_B [0:3];

always @(*)begin
    A_AND_B[0] = {4{B[0]}} & A;
    A_AND_B[1] = {4{B[1]}} & A;
    A_AND_B[2] = {4{B[2]}} & A;
    A_AND_B[3] = {4{B[3]}} & A;
end
```